# genfomtxt converting text to nan's

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to do some sentiment analysis for amazon review text with Deep Learning. Here's some examples. The 0 and 1's at the end are for bad reviews (0) and good reviews (1).

```
So there is no way for me to plug it in here in the US unless I go by a converter.  0
Good case, Excellent value. 1
Great for the jawbone.  1
Tied to charger for conversations lasting more than 45 minutes.MAJOR PROBLEMS!! 0
```

First I assign the text file to reading. I had some issues with this, if I don't include invalid_raise = False, then I get the following errors:
Line #2 (got 4 columns instead of 21)
Line #3 (got 4 columns instead of 21)
Line #4 (got 11 columns instead of 21)
Line #5 (got 4 columns instead of 21)
Line #6 (got 17 columns instead of 21)
Line #8 (got 8 columns instead of 21)

So I added invalid_raise = False and I get warnings, but it still 'works', except now when I print(reading), it just prints all nan and then the 0's and 1's. Is there a way to fix this?

```
import os
import numpy as np
import keras
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

import numpy as mp
from numpy import loadtxt

reading = np.genfromtxt("/Users/Beau/Downloads/sentiment labelled sentences/amazon_cells_labelled.txt", delimiter=" ", invalid_raise = False)
```

Comment: Nothing in your code calls `keras` or `loadtxt` or `Tokenizer` or, for that matter, `lower`.  Show us the code that's failing.

Comment: `genfomtxt` is splitting the line on space, hence the varying number of columns (words).  It also tries to convert all columns to float, and failing that assigns `nan`.  Spend more time reading its docs.  and where is the `lower` error?

Comment: My apologies. Originally, I was experiencing the Tokenizer error, however, as I went back to try to trace the error, that's when I discovered the nan error, which I'm sure was also causing tokenizer error. I updated the body of question, but forgot change the subject title. It's been updated. I will go back through the docs to try to figure out the problem. Thank you!

Comment: How many columns do you expect to parse?  Two? the text and the 0/1?  Using '.' as the delimiter might work for that.  And use `dtype=None` with that.